# Netlogo & Levelspace: how to pass strings between two child-models?

Tags: netlogo

I have three models: Parent, Child1, Child2.

Child1 generates strings which must then be passed to Child2 for further processing. The strings are generated on the fly when Child1 is executing. Whenever a new string is generated it must be sent immediately to Child2. Sometimes 2 or more strings are generated at the same time (by different agents), and then those 2 or more strings must be sent at the same time (ie. within the same tick).

One solution is to skip the parent model and let Child1 become the Parent-model, which has then access to Child 2. However, that would complicate Child1 as it would then include all the required LevelSpace code. Furthermore the two children models must be useable on their own. The two models are used for educational purposes, and the students should not see the LevelSpace code. Hence the Parent model.

Another solution is to let the Parent model continuously poll the Child 1 model to ask for new strings. Not very pretty. Not very efficient.

So basically I'm looking for some shared memory and/or event functionality in LevelSpace :-)

By the way the strings represent DNA, RNA, etc. and we're illustrating transcription and translation of strings etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Palle

Comment: Hi Palle! Good question. Basically, what you are proposing and polling the child model *is* the way to do it. 

The LevelSpace language was designed to mimic regular NetLogo in that you need to "ask" a model whether it is in some particular state, and then react to that. The alternative could be some sort of callback function that a child could invoke on its parent, but that would break with the existing conventions for NetLogo.

That said, there are certainly degrees of prettiness/efficiency in doing this. If you want specific feedback, would you mind posting the relevant code?

Comment: Thanks Arthur :-) No, that's fine. I just wanted to be sure. Line has the code, if you want a peak. Have a nice weekend, Palle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely not conventional NetLogo code, but the callback method seems like it works okay, at least for this simple example.  You do need to complicate the child models a little bit to add the `run callback` statement, but it *could* result in cleaner code overall than the polling method depending on the use case.

Parent model:

```
extensions [ ls ]

globals [ child1 child2 ]

to setup
  ls:reset
  (ls:create-models 1 "LS callback child.nlogo" [ [id] -> set child1 id ])
  (ls:create-models 1 "LS callback child.nlogo" [ [id] -> set child2 id ])
  ls:ask ls:models [
    child-setup
  ]
  ; here we set the callback for the child models
  ; we could set the callback for just `child1` instead of all `ls:models`
  ls:assign ls:models callback [ [id message] -> alert id message ]
  ls:assign child1 id child1
  ls:assign child2 id child2
end

to go
  ls:ask ls:models [
    child-go
  ]
end

; In this case our callback is simple, just taking the caller id
; and a message.  We could add more parameters for it if we want to
to alert [id message]
  show (word id ": " message)
  ; this is just to show that we can use the callback to update
  ; the state of one of the other models
  if id = 0 [
    ls:ask child2 [ set some-val (some-val + 1) ]
  ]
end
```

Child model:

```
globals [ id callback some-val ]

to child-setup
  set some-val 0
  ; set the callback to an "empty" procedure so we don't have to check
  ; if it is set while we run the go method.
  set callback [ [model-id message] -> ]
end

to child-go
  if random 10 < 3 [
    (run callback id (word "child alert: " some-val))
  ]
end
```

Sample output:

```
observer: "1: child alert: 0"
observer: "1: child alert: 0"
observer: "1: child alert: 0"
observer: "0: child alert: 0"
observer: "1: child alert: 1"
observer: "0: child alert: 0"
observer: "1: child alert: 2"
observer: "1: child alert: 2"
observer: "0: child alert: 0"
observer: "1: child alert: 3"
observer: "1: child alert: 3"
observer: "1: child alert: 3"
observer: "0: child alert: 0"
observer: "1: child alert: 4"
observer: "0: child alert: 0"
observer: "1: child alert: 5"
observer: "1: child alert: 5"
observer: "0: child alert: 0"
observer: "1: child alert: 6"
```

Every time the `child1` model runs the callback, the `alert` procedure increments the `some-val` global in `child2`.

Comment: Thanks, Jasper. I'll definitely give that a go. Although I see I really need to brush up on the anonymous procedures :-) But it looks very structured and nice. Thx!

Comment: One of the creators of LS here: this is pretty awesome, but isn't actually supposed to work. Child models, by default, run in parallel, which means there's no way to control what order they will run code in (even with `random-seed`). Normally, this is fine, since child models can't directly affect each other. But passing procedures in mean order matters a lot, so the results of the above code will be unpredictable. I've created an issue to discuss https://github.com/NetLogo/LevelSpace/issues/133

Comment: Hi,Did you try this solution. It realy looks nice-but it doesn`t work for me (Netlogo 6.1.1)

Answer (score 3):

Jasper wrote a really nice solution, though it does rely on behavior that isn't supposed to work. Another way to do it is to have `child1` collect the strings as it runs in a global variable. e.g.

Child 1 code:

```
globals [ strings ]

to go
  set strings []
  ask turtles [
    set strings lput (word "hello from turtle " who) strings
  ]
  tick
end
```

Then have `child2` accept a list of strings in its `go` method

Child 2 code:

```
to go [ strings ]
  ; do stuff with the strings
end
```

Then the parent passes the list between them:

Parent code:

```
to go
  ls:ask child1 [ go ]
  ls:let child1-strings [ strings ] ls:of child1
  ls:ask child2 [ go child1-strings ]
  tick
end
```